# Search in two properties using one search query

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

I have JSON objects which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": { "first": "John", "last": "Doe" }
    },
    {
        "name": { "first": "Foo", "last": "Bar" }
    }
]
```

My FuseJS search option is:

```
  var searchOpts = {
        shouldSort: true,
        threshold: 0.2,
        location: 0,
        distance: 100,
        maxPatternLength: 32,
        minMatchCharLength: 5,
        matchAllTokens: true,
        keys: [{
            name: "name.first", 
            weight: 0.3
        }, {
            name: "name.last",
            weight: 0.3
        }]
    }
```

What I am doing is fetching a value the user entered and searching from the object containing the names of all people.

```
var fuse = new Fuse( peopleObj, searchOpts);
var result = fuse.search( query );
```

Everything works fine as long as the user searches only using either the first name or last name, but if they for e.g type "John Doe" the object that is supposed to be returned isn't returned but does work if they only type "John" or "Doe".

I can achieve this by simply setting another property inside of the objects like `"name": {"fullName": "John Doe"}` but I am not comfortable with it since the data may get bigger in the future and this would just be a waste of processing power.

How do I make sure that FuseJS searches for the `name.first` and `name.last` property by combining them and not separately. I thought `matchAllTokens`

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior - at least not in the latest version of the library :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **fusejs** doesn't provide the search across multiple keys as of now.

You can follow the approach to combine all keys of interest into one key like

```
function combineAllKeyValues( obj, separator )
{
    separator = separator || " ";
    obj.all = Object.keys(obj.name).map(s=> obj.name[s]).join( separator );
    return obj;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var peopleObj = [{
    "name": {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Doe"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "first": "Foo",
      "last": "Bar"
    }
  }
];

var searchOpts = {
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.2,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 5,
  matchAllTokens: false,
  keys: [{
    name: "name.first",
    weight: 0.3
  }, {
    name: "name.last",
    weight: 0.3
  }, {
    name: "all",
    weight: 0.1
  }]
};

function combineAllKeyValues( obj, separator )
{
 separator = separator || " ";
 obj.all = Object.keys(obj.name).map(s=> obj.name[s]).join( separator );
 return obj;
}

peopleObj = peopleObj.map( s => combineAllKeyValues(s) );

var fuse = new Fuse( peopleObj, searchOpts);
var result = fuse.search( "John Doe" );

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.0.4/fuse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see. Seems like it is the only way to do this with FuseJS for now. Thanks for the solution though! Appreciate it.